# How to change elevation color in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, card

Hi I am creating an app with Jetpack Compose I am and using Card composable with elevation. I need to change the elevation color, but I don't know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shadow modifier. For example:

```
         modifier = Modifier
        .shadow(ambientColor = Color.Blue, elevation = 15.dp)
```

Comment: can you explain your answer, not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```kt
MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(3.dp)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).